# Text File into csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following text file that I would like to convert into a csv file:

- First line contains column number 1
- Afterwards there is a line filled with "====="
- Then there is the content of column number 2. This column can have multiple lines
- Afterwards there are 3 empty lines that indicate that the data record is finished.

For better understanding, here an example:

```
Column number 1 text
=========================
Column number 2 text
More column number 2 text
Col nr 2
More..
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
Column number 1 text
===============
Col nr 2
Col nr 2
Col nr 2
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
```

and so on....

I have tried a lot of powershell commands to do such conversion, but I haven't had any success
Could someone help me ?
It doesn't have to be a powershell script.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried (in powershell) to save the content of the file in an array with $data = Get-Content file.txt and then with a foreach loop I tried to unify the data that I want. For instance I would like to have a very simple csv: content of column nr1; content of column nr 2 and create a new line every time there is a new record

Comment: @Ajn1 Can you edit your post to include what you tried and an example of what you want the csv to look like. It's very hard to understand what your expecting from the comment above.

Comment: Note: For both your input and your output, you have to know which character encoding you want to use. Get-Content and Export-Csv do have defaults but are they what you need/want, know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PSv3+ solution that is concise, though perhaps not easy to understand:

```
Get-Content -Raw file.txt |
  Select-String -AllMatches '(.+)\r?\n=+\r?\n([\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n){3}' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches | ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Col1 = $_.Groups[1].Value
        Col2 = $_.Groups[2].Value
      }
    }
  } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv
```

- Note that the input file is read as a whole up front - this may not be an option with large input files.
- `Select-String` is used to extract the paragraphs of interest with a *regex* (regular expression).

  - Capture groups (`(...)`) inside the regex extract the column-1 and column-2 values.
  - `.+` matches all characters on a nonempty line (`.` means: any character other than `\n` (LF), and `+` means: *one or more* repetitions); in the context of the overal regex, this will capture the column-1 value.
  - `\r?\n` matches both CRLF newlines (Windows) and LF-only newlines (Unix), to be safe.
  - `=+` matches one or more adjacent `=` characters; i.e., it matches the separator line in the input.
  - `[\s\S]` is a trick to match *any* character including `\n` (LF); by default, `.` only matches characters *except* `\n`; *nongreedy* repetition symbol `*?` means that matching should stop as soon as something matches the remainder of the expression; in the context of the overall regex, this will capture the column-2 value.
  - `(?:...)` is a *noncapturing* group; we need `(...)` only to apply quantifier `{3}` to subexpression `\r?\n` (exactly 3 repetitions), but we're not interested in capturing what the subexpression matched; in the context of the overall regex, this matches the 3 empty lines at the end of each block (without capturing them).
- The `ForEach-Object` call iterates over all all matches and constructs a custom object with property names `Col1` and `Col2` from the capture-group values, which is implicitly output.
- `Export-Csv` then exports the resulting objects in CSV format to output file `out.csv`; note that the default encoding used by `Export-Csv` on Windows PowerShell is `ASCII`, so use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

---

With your sample input, `out.csv` ends up containing the following:

```
"Col1","Col2"
"Column number 1 text","Column number 2 text
More column number 2 text
Col nr 2
More.."
"Column number 1 text","Col nr 2
Col nr 2
Col nr 2"
```

Note how the `Col2` values are *multiline* values - however, `Import-Csv` handles such values fine (as long as they're double-quoted).

Comment: @AjniK: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.